# How to Store Data Property Value from a Specific Item in Rendered List in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying create a follow button on list items in Vue. My strategy is to grab the value of a particular list item property and store it in the data object. Then use this value in a method to add it to an array in my database.

```
      <div v-for="result in results" :key="result.symbol">
        {{ result.name }}
        <button @click="followStock">+follow</button>
      </div>
```

I'm not sure how to get the value of result.symbol "into" the button element to set the value symbol in the data object below.

```
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      results: [ // this is populated by an api call
                {
                 currency: "USD"
                 exchangeShortName: "NYSE"
                 name: "International Game Technology PLC"
                 stockExchange: "NYSE"
                 symbol: "IGT"
                },
                {...},
                ...
               ],
      symbol: "",
    };
  },
  
    followStock() {
      // add this.symbol to database array
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I'm guessing there might be an easier strategy I'm overlooking as I'm still new to Vue, so any other solution that essentially allows me to fire off the value of result.symbol from any rendered result to my database would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the result as a parameter to your method.

```
<div v-for="result in results" :key="result.symbol">
    {{ result.name }}
    <button @click="followStock(result)">+follow</button>
</div>
```

And in your method:

```
methods: {
    followStock(result) {
        // do something with result
        console.log({result});
        let symbol = result.symbol;
    },
}
```

P.S I didn't see you put your followStock() inside a `methods` object, but I did so in the example. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods

Answer (score 0):

Write directly as a function call.
The vue compiler will turn `followStock(result.symbol)` into `function(event) {followStock(result.symbol)}`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      results: [
        {
          name: "International Game Technology PLC",
          symbol: "IGT"
        },
        {
          name: "A name",
          symbol: "A symbol"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    followStock(symbol) {
      console.log(symbol)
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <div v-for="result in results" :key="result.symbol">
      {{ result.name }}
      <button @click="followStock(result.symbol)">+follow</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nazaire mentioned you can access the results anywhere inside the child elements when using `v-for`.

(it works like a normal `for-loop`)

It's not only limited to the corresponding element (the element in which you do v-for)

```
<div v-for="result in results" :key="result.symbol">
    {{ result.name }}
    <button @click="followStock(result.symbol)">+follow</button>
</div>

followStock(symbol){
    // you can now add symbol to db
}
```